# \Favicon.ico error in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x, jboss6.x, jboss-arquillian

I want to access my application without context root in JBoss 7.1.1
I have renamed application as ROOT.war and deployed it and 
updated stadalone.xml
from
 
to
 
Am able to access the login page of my application, but moment I enter credentials and login I get "HTTP Status 404 - /favicon.ico".

I don't know where am going wrong. once i remove /favicon from URL and reload it, everything works normal. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Favicon stands for "**Favorites Icon**". It's the little icon beside your site's name in the favorites list, before the URL in the address bar and bookmarks folder and as a bookmarked website on the desktop in some operating systems.
2. The Favicon.ico shows as `404` means is that people with browsers that use favicon (Internet Explorer 5.0 +, Firefox, Opera and a most others) are visiting your site.
   While seeing a `404` in your log files usually means that a visitor got the dreaded `"404 Page Not Found"` error, in this case it doesn't. **All it means is that the default icon was shown instead of a custom one.**
3. To get your Favicon to show there are 2 different ways to do this:

   1. This is the easiest to do and it will show your icon no matter what page your visitor adds to their favorites. Simply upload your new icon to the main directory of your site, ie. `www.example.com/favicon.ico`
   2. If you don't have access to your root directory (if your on a free server for example) or it you want a different favicon for certain pages, add this to the `<head>` of your html. (You can name your favicon whatever you'd like with this method)

      ```
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/folder-name/logo.ico">
      ```

      Or if you prefer to use the full URL:

      ```
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">
      ```

**Note:**
If you upload a new Favicon, be sure to clear your cache for the new icon to show up.

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for your suggestions. I have tired all the suggestions you provided but still no luck. Part of troubleshooting,i tried to access the application bypassing Apache web servers i.e. accessing application directly from Jboss server as http://IP:8080/. Am able to reach application login page. Once i enter my credentials and try to login i get "favicon.ico" error. i deployed application as ROOT. do we need any chnages at code level as well?